# How to insert some data into a string of AppleScript

Tags: objective-c, applescript

I have a function that sends a string "theData".  I want to insert that string here in this code.  Would someone please tell me the correct syntax for this?  Things get a bit hairy with the \"s and the "s.  Thanks!

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/osascript"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-e", @"tell application \"System Events\"\n", 
                                             @"-e", @"    keystroke \"" + theData + "\"", 
                                             @"-e", @"end tell", nil]];
[task launch];
```

Comment: There's probably a much better way to simulate keystrokes with Objective-C...

Comment: And in fact, it looks like there is. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379867/)

Comment: oooooh, just saw this.  it works flawlessly (so far) in 10.6 for me, but could this be a problem?

`CGPostKeyboardEvent Deprecated in Mac OS X v10.6`

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple%5Fref/c/func/CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString

Comment: Use CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-BBCFIDCH (Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008126/cgeventpost-possible-bug-when-simulating-keyboard-events/2079649#2079649 )

Answer (score 1):

icktoofay already gave the more correct answer, but let me just show how to insert a string in a string:

```
       NSString* toBeInserted = @"for";
       NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"in%@mation",toBeInserted]; 
       NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

This gives `information`.  For more details, read [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i).

I mean, Apple's doc is quite good, actually. Read it before asking a question here at SO.

By the way, you don't have to launch `osascript` to execute AppleScript. You can use [`NSAppleScript`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as in

```
NSAppleScript* script=[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell app \"Finder\" to activate "];
NSDictionary*error;
[script executeAndReturnError:&error];
[script release];
```

Well, `NSAppleScript` is an oddity which requires `NSDictionary`, not an `NSError`, to report an error ...

Or, you can use [Scripting Bridge](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104) to map AppleScript objects to Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have another way of doing it, but you can use  format strings to accomplish this

```
[NSString stringWIthFormat: @"part one %@ part 2", theData];
```

Assuming the data is an nsstring containing "hello", this will give you:

```
@"part one hello part 2"
```