# how do i enable screen zoom/magnification programmatically under os x?

Tags: macos, accessibility

i'm talking about the "zoom" functionality in the universal access system preference panel. normally this is accomplished with command–option–8. then the zoom controls are command–option–+ (magnify) and command–option–- (minus/minify).

my most recent attempt involved [sending the keypresses for the shortcuts as events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008126/cgeventpost-possible-bug-when-simulating-keyboard-events). however this approach has serious [bugs](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2009/Oct/msg00087.html). on top of that, i don't know whether the user already has zoom enabled. i'm looking for something cleaner. like, the way you're supposed to do it.

of course there is always using applescript to open the system preferences pane and toggle the radio buttons, but that is not really what i would call "clean."

even if you don't know exactly how to accomplish what i'm asking, even some pointers as to where this kind of thing (programmatic toggling of os functionality) might be documented would be helpful. the language doesn't matter. thanks.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to do this. If someone needs magnification turned on they should do it them selves. If you want to use the built in magnification to change the size of your software write your own code to do this instead of relying on the built in magnifyer. As a user of screen reading software nothing would get me to stop using a program quicker then that program messing with my configured accessibility settings which I've spent years getting just right.

Comment: jared: without going into too much detail, my program is the driver component of an alternate way of controlling the cursor. it will often be used with the screen magnifier. i need to change the sensitivity of the input in concert with the current screen magnification. the best way to do that that i can think of from a user experience perspective is to operate the screen magnification from within the program. so the os's built-in screen magnification facility and my program become one. of course the user can operate the magnifier separately as well, but it's more work for them that way.

Answer (score 1):

it's not quite what i wanted, but `UAZoomEnabled()` in `/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Headers/UniversalAccess.h` lets me know whether zoom is currently enabled. then i know whether to send the command-option-8 keystrokes using `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent()`, `CGEventSetFlags()` and `CGEventPost()`. in order to make sure that they're zoomed in 10 ticks, i zoom out 100 ticks, then zoom in 10 ticks.

source: http://lists.apple.com/archives/accessibility-dev/2011/Mar/msg00013.html