# How do I keep a key pressed using CGEventPost in C++ on OSX?

Tags: c++, c, macos, keyboard, keypress

I'm using ApplicationServices and CGEventPost in C++ on OSX and I'm trying to see if I can hold a key down but it's not working.

Here is the method I'm using:

```
void postKeyboardEvent( int keyCode, bool keyUp = false )
{

    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate( kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState );

    CGEventRef keyEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( source, (CGKeyCode) keyCode, !keyUp );
    CGEventPost( kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, keyEvent );
    CFRelease( keyEvent );

    CFRelease( source );

}
```

This is how I am testing it:

```
postKeyboardEvent( kVK_Command );
postKeyboardEvent( kVK_Tab );
postKeyboardEvent( kVK_Tab, true );
postKeyboardEvent( kVK_Command, true );
```

By my understanding this should toggle me to another window but instead it just "lets go of" the Command key and types a Tab character.

IMPORTANT: I don't want to use something like the following:

```
CGEventSetFlags( keyEvent, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand );
```

I have a need to send a "serial chain" of key-down and key-up commands *without* having to know which key-codes are modifier keys or how many to flag the event with.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/8202467/877860 posted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/314546/valexa

> The simplest way for this is just bitwise OR'ing the current modifier
>   flags with the flag of your desired modifier(s) , e.g.:
>
> ```
> CGEventFlags flags = kCGEventFlagMaskShift;
> CGEventRef ev;
> CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate (kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
>
> //press down            
> ev = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (source, keyCode, true);    
> CGEventSetFlags(ev,flags | CGEventGetFlags(ev)); //combine flags                        
> CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap,ev);
> CFRelease(ev);              
>
> //press up                                  
> ev = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (source, keyCode, false);                       
> CGEventSetFlags(ev,flags | CGEventGetFlags(ev)); //combine flags                        
> CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap,ev); 
> CFRelease(ev);              
>
> CFRelease(source);
> ```

**UPDATE:**
This is the method I landed on, it could use some clean-up but it works quite well for my purposes of dispatching a sequence of keycodes to the system and having them happen predictably.

A very important element here is the bitwise operation to remove the shift key mask if shift is NOT down using `(& ~)` meaning AND NOT.

```
int shiftKeyCode = 56;
bool shiftIsDown = false;

void postKeyboardEvent( int keyCode, bool keyUp = false )
{

    // Don't send keys while blocked.
    if( blockState == 1 ){

        return;

    }

    if( keyCode == shiftKeyCode ){

        if( keyUp ){

            shiftIsDown = false;

        }else{

            shiftIsDown = true;

        }

    }

    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate( kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState );
    CGEventRef keyEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( source, (CGKeyCode) keyCode, !keyUp );

    if( shiftIsDown ){

        // Use Shift flag
        CGEventSetFlags( keyEvent, CGEventGetFlags( keyEvent ) | kCGEventFlagMaskShift );

    }else{

        // Use all existing flag except Shift
        CGEventSetFlags( keyEvent, CGEventGetFlags( keyEvent ) & ~kCGEventFlagMaskShift );

    }

    CGEventPost( kCGHIDEventTap, keyEvent );

    CFRelease( keyEvent );
    CFRelease( source );

}
```

Comment: This is old, Apple may have changed things, I haven't worked with this in quite a while so I don't know if it works in the latest OSX.