# Close NSTokenField completion list when an item is clicked?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstokenfield

I have an NSTokenField in my app. When I click one of the suggestions from the completion list, I would like the list to disappear and the token to be completed (like Mail) However, this doesn't seem to be happening--clicking a suggestion just appends the remainder of the string and the list doesn't disappear.

The completion list disappers if I press Return, but I want it to be dismissed by clicking a suggestion as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to this problem, which is not perfect yet but I hope I will soon solve the last issue I have.

I'm using rubymotion and even if I can translate `Objective-C` in `Ruby`, I'm not able to do the opposite so my answer will be in `Ruby`. Feel free to edit my answer to add the corresponding `Objective-C` code.

In the delegate of my `NSTokenField`, I used the [controlTextDidChange](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method of `NSControl` which is called anytime I write a character in my token field. In this method I check if there is a `NSLeftMouseUp` event which is triggered, and if it's the case, I simulate a click on `Return` (learned from this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008126/cgeventpost-possible-bug-when-simulating-keyboard-events)). And that's it.

Here is my `Ruby` code:

```
def controlTextDidChange(aNotification)
  application = NSApplication.sharedApplication
  event = application.currentEvent
  if event.type == NSLeftMouseUp
    e1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 0x24, true)
    CGEventPost(KCGSessionEventTap, e1)
  end
end
```

But like I told you, it's not perfect yet: my issue is that if I have a completion list with 3 items for instance, one of them will be selected by default, let's say the first one. In this case, my solution will work as expected if I click the second or the third item but I will have to double click the first item to make it work.

But still, it's a good start and I hope it will help!

**EDIT**

To fix the last issue I had, I turned off the autocompletion and only displayed the suggestion box. To do so, I added this line to the `tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:` method:

```
selectedIndex[0] = -1
```

Comment: Tried to add in the Objective-C code to your answer but my edits are being rejected... =(

Comment: if([[NSApplication sharedApplication]currentEvent].type == NSLeftMouseUp)
    {
        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 0x24, true));
    }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @**siekfried**!

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
{
    if([[NSApplication sharedApplication]currentEvent].type == NSLeftMouseUp)
    {
        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 0x24, true));
    }
}
```

works really well ;)

to avoid the first element automatic selection add this to your delegate:

```
-(NSArray *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex
{
    *selectedIndex = -1;
...
...
}
```