# type lowercase letters after using CGEventSetFlags

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to do some uppercase key strokes, followed by lowercase with Cocoa. Example: `AaAaaA`

For uppercase stroke I use  `CGEventSetFlags(key, CGEventFlags.MaskShift)`

But then, I want to press the same letter, but this time in lowercase. All my KeyboardEvents are in uppercase. How do I shit to lowercase after using uppercase?

Found this question [CGEventPost - possible bug when simulating keyboard events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008126/cgeventpost-possible-bug-when-simulating-keyboard-events). My problem is basically the same, but it requires Swift solution. Bitwise flags are beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Are you using a `UITextField` for the text input?

Comment: Not really. Basically whatever user desires.

Comment: If you can use a `UITextField`, use the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol method `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`, this would allow you to use the `.lowercased()` method from the Swift String API to take the last character out of the textField's text, make it a string, and make it lowercased like `stringName.lowercased()`, and then append that string, and update the actual text.